# How to import a jquery script into a vue file

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I want to add a simple jquery script in my vue file. I tried to import it by using this method:

**in the vue file**

```
import {myScript} from "@/components/scripts/myScript.js"
```

**then in the myScript.js file :**

```
export const myScript = {
  $('.class').addCLass('anotherClass');
}
```

It returns a problem of syntax.

Thx

Comment: At least here you have a small typo mistake instead of `addCLass` (with an capital L) it should be `addClass`. Do you have this also in your code?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export function MyScript () {
   $('.class').addClass('anotherClass');
}

import {MyScript} from "@/components/scripts/myScript.js"

MyScript();
```

Comment: Hello, your answer helped me, it works ;) ! Thx a lot !